# how to set click event and name to a array of button dynamically created

Tags: c#, wpf

I created 8*8 matrix of button for Minesweeper Game. I need to set click event and name to them. How can I do that? Help please. Also I used canvas to create the grid. Is it the best way to do that?

```
private void makeGrid()
    {
        int firstlp,secondlp,position=50;
        for (int i = 0; i < 400; i=i+50)
        {
            for (secondlp = 0; secondlp < 400; secondlp = secondlp + 50)
            {
                Button lbl = new Button()
                {

                    Content = "",
                    HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right,
                    VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center,
                    HorizontalContentAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center,
                    VerticalContentAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center,
                    Height = 50,
                    Width = 50,
                };
                jereMy.Children.Add(lbl);
                Canvas.SetLeft(lbl, secondlp + 50);
                Canvas.SetRight(lbl, secondlp + 50);
                Canvas.SetTop(lbl, position);
            }
            position = position + 50;
        }  

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the EventHandler and name when creating the Button:

```
lbl.Click += button_Click;
lbl.Name = string.Format("btn_{0}_{1}",i,secondlp);
```

The EventHandler should look like this:

```
private void button_Click ( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e )
{
  // Handle the click event
}
```

And I'd suggest to use a [`UniformGrid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.UniformGrid.aspx) instead of `Canvas`. You can use the properties `Rows`and `Columns` to  make the UnformGrid 8x8.
There are a lot of layout panels in WPF, I think most of them fit your needs better than Canvas. (e.g. `Grid` or nested `StackPanel`s)

Answer (score 1):

You can add a event registerion such as below.

```
lbl.Click+= OnButtonClick(sender,e);


private void OnButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //To do.
}
```